# C8051f06 16-bit SAR ADC is always reading on maximum even when it is not connected to anything

Tags: microcontroller, adc, grounding

I recently fabricated a circuit based on the C8051f06 reference design.

When I test the 16bit SAR ADC example code, the values are always on maximum value.

I have the idea that my soldering iron is noisy since it is a regular AC iron that could damage the ADC input when soldering. Maybe it is a problem with the DC offset - when it is grounded there might be noises causing the problem.

Can any one help with testing? What can I do to find out if the ADC is faulty or not?

the following is the layout that i used , i did not connect the driver circuitry yet via R21 is disconnected .

i am reading the values using the serial port Uart0
and the values are always " 65535 " that is the max of the output , no matter what i connect to it .

[image: image layout]

the datasheet of the reference design is in here  :
[Datasheet With the reference design](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/user-guides/C8051F06x-DK.pdf)

and the code is

```
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// F06x_SAR16Data.c
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (C) 2005 Silicon Laboratories, Inc.
//
//
// Data Acquisition example for 'F06x
//
// Target: C8051F060TB Target Board
//
// Description: This example illustrates the use of ADC1 and the DMA to     acquire and store
// data.  It is intended for use with the C8051F060TB target board in the development kit.
//
// This code measures a signal at the AIN0 input with the 16-bit SAR ADC0.
// The data is sampled at a rate of 100kHz.  ADC output data is transferred to
// XDATA memory space using the DMA.
//
// With the EMIF configured for off-chip XRAM access (on the upper ports),
// this code moves the ADC data to the C8051F060TB target boards's SRAM device.
// Once data acquisition is complete, the code then prompts the user to press the P3.7
// button on the target board when ready to receive the data via the UART0 serial port.
// The TB features an RS-232 transceiver and connector, so the data can be transferred
// to a PC via its serial port.
//
// The code is set to acquire up to 32768 samples (for 64kbytes of data).  The SRAM device
// can accommodate up to 128kbytes, but this requires banking (A16 signal on the SRAM).
//
// Target Board Configuration:  This example uses RS-232 communications, typically with
// a PC.  A serial cable should be connected to the J5 RS-232 DB-9 connector on the
// target board and to a serial port on a PC.  (A serial port will also be needed for
// PC communications with the EC-2 serial adapter for programming and debug).
// Data can be input from the PC's serial port using commonly available Hyperterminal.
// The following target board jumpers must be configured (see user's guide for schematic):
//
//   J2: installed (voltage supply)
//   J6 and J9: installed (RS-232 combs)
//   J17 and J28: installed (external voltage reference for SIR)
//   J11: installed (SRAM chip select)
//   J14: Installed to connect to (SRAM) A16 to GND, and NOT P3.7 which will be used
//        for push-button
//   J1: Installed to connect P3.7 to push-button.
//   J20: Installed to enable +/-5V switching power supply. Connect pin 1 (Van, +5V) to
//        pin 2 (/SHIN).
//
// See the User's Guide for additional information and jumper connection information.
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Includes
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <c8051f060.h>                    // SFR declarations
#include <stdio.h>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 16-bit SFR Definitions for 'F06x
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

sfr16 RCAP3    = 0xCA;                 // Timer3 reload value
sfr16 TMR3     = 0xCC;                 // Timer3 counter

sfr16 ADC0     = 0xBE;                 // ADC0 Data
sfr16 ADC1     = 0xBE;                 // ADC1 Data

sfr16 DMA0DS   = 0xDB;                 // DMA0 XRAM Address Pointer
sfr16 DMA0CT   = 0xF9;                 // DMA0 Repeat Counter Limit
sfr16 DMA0DA   = 0xD9;                 // DMA0 Address Beginning
sfr16 DMA0CS   = 0xFB;                 // DMA0 Repeat Counter


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global CONSTANTS
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define SYSCLK 25000000 //22118400                   // SYSCLK frequency in Hz
#define BAUDRATE 115200                   // Baud Rate for UART0

// DMA INSTRUCTIONS

#define DMA0_END_OF_OP     0x00           // End-of-Operation
#define DMA0_END_OF_OP_C   0x80           // End-of-Operation + Continue
#define DMA0_GET_ADC0      0x10           // Retrieve ADC0 Data
#define DMA0_GET_ADC1      0x20           // Retrieve ADC1 Data
#define DMA0_GET_ADC01     0x30           // Retrieve ADC0 and ADC1 Data
#define DMA0_GET_DIFF      0x40           // Retrieve Differential Data
#define DMA0_GET_DIFF1     0x60           // Retrieve Differential and ADC1 Data


#define NUM_SAMPLES        32768          // Number of ADC sample to acquire (each sample 2 bytes)
#define XRAM_START_ADD     0x0000         // DMA0 XRAM Start address of ADC data log
#define SAMP_RATE          100000         // ADC sample rate in Hz


sbit LED = P0^7;                          // LED: '1' = ON; '0' = OFF
sbit BUTTON = P3^7;                       // pushbutton on the target board
sbit RAM_CS = P4^5;                       // chip select bit is P4^4

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Function PROTOTYPES
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void SYSCLK_Init (void);
void UART0_Init (void);
void PORT_Init (void);
void ADC0_Init (void);
void ADC1_Init (void);
void DMA0_Init (void);
void Timer3_Init (int counts);
void EMIF_Init (void);
void SendData(void);

//-------------------------
// Global Variables
//-------------------------
unsigned char Conv_Complete = 0;
unsigned int xdata * data read_ptr;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// MAIN Routine
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main (void)
{
   WDTCN = 0xde;                          // disable watchdog timer
   WDTCN = 0xad;

   SYSCLK_Init ();                        // initialize SYSCLK

   PORT_Init ();

   EMIF_Init ();                          // Storing ADC samples in SRAM on the
                                          // target board.
   SFRPAGE = CONFIG_PAGE;

   RAM_CS = 0;                            // assert SRAM chip select

   UART0_Init ();                         // initialize UART0

   Timer3_Init (SYSCLK/SAMP_RATE);        // Init Timer3 for 100ksps sample rate

   ADC0_Init ();                          // configure ADC0 and ADC1 for differential
                                          // measurement.

   DMA0_Init ();                          // Configure DMA to move NUM_SAMP samples.


   SFRPAGE = UART0_PAGE;
   printf ("Data Acquisition in progress...\n");

   SFRPAGE = DMA0_PAGE;                   // Switch to DMA0 Page

   while (!(DMA0CN & 0x40));              // Wait for DMA to obtain and move ADC samples
                                          // by polling DMA0INT bit.

   SFRPAGE = LEGACY_PAGE;
   printf ("Data Acquisition complete.\nPress P3.7 button when ready to receive file.\n");

   while (BUTTON != 0);                   // Wait for user to press P3.7 on the TB.

   SendData();                            // Send data via the UART0.
   
   SFRPAGE = LEGACY_PAGE;
   printf ("transmission is done.\n");

   while(1);                              // Done.


}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// PORT_Init
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Configure the Crossbar and GPIO ports
//
void PORT_Init (void)
{
char old_SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE;

   SFRPAGE = CONFIG_PAGE;              // Switch to configuration page


   XBR0    = 0x04;                     // Enable UART0 on crossbar
   XBR1    = 0x00;
   XBR2    = 0x40;                     // Enable crossbar and weak pull-ups
   P0MDOUT |= 0xFF;                    // enable Port0 outputs as push-pull

   SFRPAGE = old_SFRPAGE;              // restore SFRPAGE
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// UART0_Init
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Configure the UART0 using Timer1, for <baudrate> and 8-N-1.
//
void UART0_Init (void)
{
char old_SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE;

   SFRPAGE = UART0_PAGE;               // Switch to UART0 page

   SCON0   = 0x50;                     // SCON: mode 1, 8-bit UART, enable RX
   SSTA0 = 0x10;                       // Timer 1 generates UART0 baud rate and
                                       // UART0 baud rate divide by two disabled

   SFRPAGE = TIMER01_PAGE;             // Switch to Timer 0/1 page

   TMOD   = 0x20;                      // TMOD: timer 1, mode 2, 8-bit reload
   TH1    = -(SYSCLK/BAUDRATE/16);     // set Timer1 reload value for baudrate
   TR1    = 1;                         // start Timer1
   CKCON |= 0x10;                      // Timer1 uses SYSCLK as time base
   PCON  |= 0x80;                      // SMOD = 1

   SFRPAGE = UART0_PAGE;               // Switch to UART0 page

   TI0    = 1;                         // Indicate TX ready

   SFRPAGE = old_SFRPAGE;              // restore SFRPAGE

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SYSCLK_Init
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void SYSCLK_Init (void)
{
/*   char old_SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE;
   int i;                                 

   SFRPAGE = CONFIG_PAGE;              // Switch to Configuration Page

   OSCXCN = 0x67;                      // start external oscillator with
                                       // 22.1184MHz crystal on TB

   for (i=0; i <5000; i++) ;           // XTLVLD blanking interval (>1ms)

   while (!(OSCXCN & 0x80)) ;          // Wait for crystal osc. to settle

   RSTSRC = 0x04;                      // enable missing clock detector reset

   CLKSEL = 0x01;                      // change to external crystal

   OSCICN = 0x00;                      // disable internal oscillator



   SFRPAGE = old_SFRPAGE;              // restore SFRPAGE*/
      char SFRPAGE_save = SFRPAGE;        // Save Current SFR page

   SFRPAGE = CONFIG_PAGE;              // Set SFR page

   OSCICN = 0x83;                      // Set internal oscillator to run
                                       // at its maximum frequency

   CLKSEL = 0x00;                      // Select the internal osc. as
                                       // the SYSCLK source

   SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE_save;             // Restore SFR page
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ADC0_Init
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ADC0_Init (void)
{
   char old_SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE;
   int i;

   SFRPAGE = ADC0_PAGE;                // Switch to ADC0 Page

   ADC0CN = 0x44;                      // ADC Disabled, Timer3 start-of-conversion
                                       // track 16 SAR clocks before data conversion
                                       // upon Timer3 OV.  DMA will enable ADC as needed
                                       //

   REF0CN = 0x03;                      // turn on bias generator and internal reference.

   for(i=0;i<10000;i++);               // Wait for Vref to settle (large cap used on target board)

   AMX0SL = 0x00;                      // Single-ended mode

   ADC0CF = (SYSCLK/25000000) << 4;    // Select SAR clock frequency =~ 25MHz

   SFRPAGE = old_SFRPAGE;              // restore SFRPAGE
}



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// DMA0_Init
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void DMA0_Init (void)
{
   char old_SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE;

   SFRPAGE = DMA0_PAGE;                // Switch to DMA0 Page

   DMA0CN = 0x00;                      // Disable DMA interface

   DMA0DA = XRAM_START_ADD;            // Starting Point for XRAM addressing

   DMA0CT = NUM_SAMPLES;               // Get NUM_SAMPLES samples

   DMA0IPT = 0x00;                     // Start writing at location 0

   // Push instructions onto stack in order they will be executed
   DMA0IDT = DMA0_GET_ADC0;            // DMA to move ADC0 data.
   DMA0IDT = DMA0_END_OF_OP;

   DMA0BND = 0x00;                     // Begin instruction executions at address 0
   DMA0CN = 0xA0;                      // Mode 1 Operations, Begin Executing DMA Ops
                                       // (which will start ADC0)

   SFRPAGE = old_SFRPAGE;              // restore SFRPAGE
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Timer3_Init
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Configure Timer3 to auto-reload and generate ADC sample rate
// specified by <counts> using SYSCLK as its time base.
//
void Timer3_Init (int counts)
{
   char old_SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE;

   SFRPAGE = TMR3_PAGE;                // Switch to Timer 3 page

   TMR3CN = 0x00;                      // Stop Timer3; Clear TF3;
   TMR3CF = 0x08;                      // use SYSCLK as timebase
   RCAP3   = -counts;                  // Init reload values
   TMR3    = 0xffff;                   // set to reload immediately
   TR3 = 1;                            // start Timer3

   SFRPAGE = old_SFRPAGE;              // restore SFRPAGE
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// EMIF_Init
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Configure the external memory interface to use upper port pins in
// non-multiplexed mode to a mixed on-chip/off-chip configuration without
// Bank Select.
//
void EMIF_Init (void)
{
   char SFRPAGE_SAVE = SFRPAGE;        // Save Current SFR page

   SFRPAGE = EMI0_PAGE;                // Save SFR_PAGE
   EMI0CF = 0x3C;                      // upper ports; non-muxed mode;
                                       // split mode w/o bank select
   EMI0TC = 0x45;                      // timing (7-cycle MOVX)

   SFRPAGE = CONFIG_PAGE;
   P4MDOUT |= 0xFF;                    // all EMIF pins configured as
   P5MDOUT |= 0xFF;                    // push-pull
   P6MDOUT |= 0xFF;
   P7MDOUT |= 0xFF;

   SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE_SAVE;             // restore SFR_PAGE
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SendData
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//Send data out UART0 
//
void SendData(void)
{
   unsigned int i;
   char old_SFRPAGE = SFRPAGE;
   SFRPAGE = UART0_PAGE;               // Switch to UART0 page

   read_ptr = XRAM_START_ADD;          // Set pointer to beginning of data

   for (i=0;i<NUM_SAMPLES;i=i+3 )
   {
   printf ("%u\n",*read_ptr);          // Send data as unsigned integers
   read_ptr++;
   printf ("%u\n",*read_ptr);
   read_ptr++;
   printf ("%u\n",*read_ptr);
   read_ptr++;
   }

   SFRPAGE = old_SFRPAGE;

}//End
```

code here

Comment: Connect it to something and retest.

Comment: What result would you expect when reading an unconnected analog input and why?

Comment: i connected it to ground it should give Zero , and i did connect it to Mixed signal generator , how ever the values does not change , its always in max

Comment: @22IONIC - Hi, Please edit the question and add (a) your full schematic, (b) link to that specific MCU datasheet, (c) your [minimal, but still complete, code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), (d) specific details of this "maximum value" you report is being returned and how you are reading it (serial port? LEDs?), and (e) some photos of your hardware, some with only the PCB and some wider shots showing relevant wiring, in case that highlights any issues which readers can see. Thanks :-)

Comment: @SamGibson i did that

Comment: @22IONIC - Thanks for the update, but: "*i did that*" - no, you didn't supply what I requested (a) Are you saying your schematic is *exactly* the same as the linked document? (b) Not supplied. (c) Not supplied - that code is far from minimal. It captures 32k samples using DMA. *But* as it is example code from the manufacturer, it *should* be OK. (d) Understood, thanks. (e) No photos supplied at all. Only a partial (and unreadable) PCB layout. (f) (new) "*i did not connect the driver circuitry yet via R21 is disconnected*". Your update isn't clear which analog conditioning components [...]

Comment: (cont'd)  [...] (e.g. U6, U7 etc.) are installed & where the i/p signal is injected. Did you use an oscilloscope on the actual MCU AIN0 pin? || So as you can see, no, I didn't get most of what I requested. Unless your replies improve in terms of clarity, detail, and matching what people request, then IMHO it will be impossible to help you within a few comments. Remember that on Stack Exchange, long comment threads for troubleshooting are generally discouraged, and chat would still need lots of effort from you. Please improve your update, if you can, or suggest another way to make progress.

Comment: i am sorry sir @SamGibson